How would I duplicate these animations?
Alright so I want to create a big battlefield within this scene. I used some mixamo animations with some characters to replicate a sword fight. I want to duplicate this sword fight so I can have many battles happening around the battle field. How would I do this? I have tried selecting all of the rigs, along with the objects that the rigs are attached to, and duplicating them, but there always seems to be something deformed. I don't want to manually fix every duplicated animations because I plan on adding a lot of "battles".

Hello, hard to say, maybe share the armature + mesh?

Thanks for the response. I'm not sure what you mean by "share the armature and mesh". I'll try to explain it further. I misspoke when I said that the armature/mesh was deforming when I duplicated it - it's not. The problem is that when I move the duplicated armature and mesh, some objects(like the sword and shield) move way faster than the main mesh(the body). If they moved at the same speed, I would be easily able to move all of the animations to a different location on the battlefield. Do you know what I can do to fix this?

@DylanEasley i think they mean share the blend file

Yea sorry I don't think I can. The file is super big

If anyone cares, I actually figured it out with a little research.
I made sure that every object and rig was inside one collection. After that, I pressed "Shift + A", and clicked 'Collection Instance". I then clicked the collection that I wanted to duplicate and for this case it was "Battle 1". This duplicated everything without deforming anything!
